How to change the colors of a graph when using a package in R?
I am starting to use R, so I am not familiar with the language. Currently I am using the package qPCRtools to analyze my real-time PCR data, and in order to publish my results I need to change the graph colors. Does anyone knows how can I do it?
qPCRtools package:https://github.com/lixiang117423/qPCRtools/tree/main/R
** I am using the function CalExpCurve.
This is the part of the code that generates the graph:

The graph:

I've tried different functions to change the graph color but doesn't work. I noticed that ggplot2 was used in the 'qPCRtools' package, so I am not sure if this part of the code has something to do with it:

Thank you!

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post code or data in images What colors do you want? What exactly did you try?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Without a reproducible example, it's hard to check any solution. That said, the object res[["figure"]] in your code should be a ggplot object, since that is what is returned by CalExpCurve(). ggplot objects can be modified using functions from the ggplot2 package. If you want to change the colours of the bars, you can do that using the scale_fill_manual() function from ggplot2.
The lack of a reproducible example means I can't write a complete section of code to demonstrate the solution, but the solution will probably look something like this:
res[["figure"]] +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    "CC" = "red", 
    "EX24" = "blue", 
    "EX6" = "green", 
    "FHV48" = "purple", 
    "V" = "black"
  ))

You can specify colours using either R's built-in colour names, hexadecimal colours (e.g. #FF0000) or by using the rgb() function. As an alternative, you could also make use of the colour combinations that are built into ggplot2, since these use combinations that are suitable for people with colourblindness, for example. These built-in colour combinations include scale_colour_brewer() and scale_colour_viridis_d().
